# Meaning of the sentence "He has come for five days."?

Tags: present-perfect

I encounter the sentence in a dictionary, but it makes me confused a lot!
"come" is a punctual verb and "for five days" is a period of time.

fr：《葛传椝英语惯用法词典》
[image]

Comment: I can perhaps see why. 'He has slept for five days' means 'He has been asleep/sleeping for five days' (!!!) 'He has walked for five days' means 'He has been walking (probably with breaks) for five days.' BUT  'He has come for five days' cannot be analysed the same way, though it looks similar in form. It means 'He has come here, intending to stay five days'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I updated the information just now. Your explanation is the answer the dictionary shows. But why? I  thought it means "He has come here several times in five days."

Comment: Your post is very confusing. Dictionaries define words, not sentences. What is a punctual verb? Which dictionary? For what entry?

Comment: It's a typical usage of come / go + directional (home, here, to Wigan...); it often has a temporal adjunct (for good, for Easter, for two weeks ...) showing length of intended /actual (past events) stay.

Comment: @cenwun That's not an unreasonable parsing, but that would be better expressed as "He has been coming for 5 days" - that would connect the past action of coming to the fact that the coming is still happening. Saying "he has come for 5 days" suggests a connection to the present (he's still here), but puts the action of coming firmly in the past (he came once and stayed).

Comment: Please give the actual quote from, attribution of and link to, the dictionary you mention.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you have some more examples about this epecial usage of come/go in perfect aspect? It is the perfect aspect that confuses me so much! Is it another possible meaning for the sentence that means "He has come here several times in five days." which emphasizes the number of times?

Comment: @NuclearWang He has come for five days.=means, at the time the sentence is said in the present, the guy is still there.

Comment: @Lambie Which is exactly what I said, re-read my last sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in 《葛传椝英语惯用法词典》

Comment: Please give a link.

Comment: [Colloquial Czech: The Complete Course for Beginners
By James Naughton](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ArpgCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=%22come+for+a+week%22+meaning&source=bl&ots=QRNXuEHjcJ&sig=ACfU3U12g2rLWzrDVBPEHvVu7fzmMSFulQ&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22come%20for%20a%20week%22%20meaning&f=false) (!!) has "I'll come for a week" = "I'll come to stay for a week". // Note that "I can't come for a couple of weeks" usually has the different meaning "I won't be able to come until two weeks from now". Though it _could_ mean "... I can only stay 8 days maximum".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have updated it in the question description with a picture of the dictionary.

Comment: @NuclearWang Well, I find it confusing.

Comment: "He has come here on five occasions" certainly shows a repetitive action. But "He has come here to see his parents" **usually** just refers to a single event, with the implication that he's still here. "He has come here several times over the years to see his parents" flips back to the repetitive meaning, of course.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see, you mean "come" is a double action verb. The sentence "He has come for five days."  equates to "He has come to stay for five days.". What I mentioned above about the number of times confuses with the perfect present tense. SO, the sentence “He has beening coming for five days."  equates to "He has been coming to stay for five days."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How the sentence you gave above "I can't come for a couple of weeks." has a possible meaning of  "... I can only stay 8 days maximum"？ “A couple of weeks” is two weeks, 14 days? or 8 days?

Comment: "I can't come for a couple of weeks" _could_ mean "I can't stay for a whole two weeks" (though it would be an unusual choice to convey this). I was just giving an example follow-on sentence to clarify the meaning. It could have been "I can only stay 11 days at the most" or "I can only stay _one_ week".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

> He has come for five days.

This could mean either he has come and intends to stay for five days, or he has come each day for five days.

In either case, the "coming" is a single event without duration in time. In the first case, "for five days" indicates something about the purpose of the coming (to stay for 5 days), and in the second case "for five days" describes how the action of coming has been repeated regularly over a certain period of time.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. If I meant "he has come every day for five days" I think I would say just that - or possibly "he has come for five days in succession".